# I am reading a stream of bytes from server using esp8266 by running a .php script on the server but i do not get the correct data

Tags: php, html, c, arduino, esp8266

This is the GET request & response which is sent/received to/from the server

Connecting to MD1
.......
WiFi connected
IP address: 
192.168.43.135
connecting to smbbitumen.com
Requesting URL: http://www.smbbitumen.com/smbbitumen.com/myftp/API/Users/read.php
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 06 Jun 2020 03:00:17 GMT
Server: nginx/1.17.9
Content-Type: text/html
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Accept-Ranges: none
X-Server-Cache: true
X-Proxy-Cache: MISS
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

48
1111000019:30:0020:30:0019:40:0020:40:0019:45:0020:45:0019:50:0020:50:00
0

closing connection

---

1111000019:30:0020:30:0019:40:0020:40:0019:45:0020:45:0019:50:0020:50:00 -> This is the stream of data which i am reading into esp but it does not get updated in realtime, it remains same. Any ideas, ehy this is happening.....

Also one more thing, when i run the above php link in browser,everytime it returns correct data.

---

php script which i am using to read data

```
<?php
clearstatcache();
$myfile = fopen("TEST.txt", "r");
if($myFile === FALSE)
    echo "ERROR";
else
    echo fread($myfile,filesize("TEST.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

ESP8266 code for connecting to server and running the above script using GET request

```
   #include <NTPClient.h>
   #include <WiFiUdp.h>
   #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
   #include <WiFiClient.h>
   #include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
   #include <WiFiClientSecure.h> 
   #include <Ticker.h>
   #include <EEPROM.h>
   #include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
   #include<ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>


   const char *ssid = "***";
   const char *password = "******";
   HTTPClient myhttp;


    void setup()
    {
        Serial.begin(115200);
        WiFi.begin(ssid,password);

        while(WiFi.status()!= WL_CONNECTED)
        {
            delay(1000);
            Serial.println("Connecting...");
        }
     }

    void loop()
    {
      if(WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
      {
  myhttp.begin("http://www.smbbitumen.com/smbbitumen.com/myftp/API/Users/read.php");
       int httpCode = myhttp.GET();

       if(httpCode > 0)
       {
          String payload = myhttp.getString();
          Serial.println(myhttp.getString());

       }
         httpCode = 0;
         myhttp.end();
      }
        delay(2000);
    }
```

Comment: @Juraj. It was working well earlier but this problem started to happen two weeks before only.

Comment: @Makyen Sorry for providing incomplete information, i have updated the code. Will wait for the inputs....seems like a cache problem but need your suggestions.

Comment: @Makyen - I have uploaded* the code

Comment: @Makyen Added C to Question(s) tag

Comment: I still don't understand what is the problem. btw. Arduino is C++, but it is better to tag with [arduino]

Answer (score -1):

The issue is related to cache. Change the code in read.php as below

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
clearstatcache();
$myfile = fopen("TEST.txt", "r");
if($myFile === FALSE)
    echo "ERROR";
else
    echo fread($myfile,filesize("TEST.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
clearstatcache();

?>
```

The similar thing can be done by changing the settings for cache on the server.

Comment: you think OP has a cache on server? because the MCU doesn't have a cache